# Proper formating for XSLT including WordProcessigML (OpenXML)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xslt, openxml, wordprocessingml

I have XSLT file which I'd like to edit in Visual Studio (2010). The template is used to transform input data-XML to OpenXML format (MS Word document). Visual Studio is failing to format it properly (split to multiple lines and indent). Selected line on the [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndibe.png) (starts with `<wx:sect>` tag) is just mile-long and not affected by `Edit > Format Document (Format Section)`. Inside this line is a whole description of Word document.

[image: unformatable line]

What i need to do (to install may be) so VS could format such file?

Comment: check the word Document node, it has an attribute `xml:space="preserve"` if you remove it for editing it should format correctly

Comment: Wow thats worked thanks a lot @TobiasKlevenz ! Though I don't understand why =)

Comment: They use it to preserve whitespace inbetween text blocks, basically to make up for their badly designed XML structure. If you copy large chunks of text blocks and end up with missing spaces between words you can try adding it back.

Comment: Thanks, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving to 2003 WordML, Word puts `xml:space="preserve"` in the root node of the document to make up for their badly designed XML structure, this keeps the code from *pretty printing* in an Editor.

If it is removed, formatting the document will work.

Word uses this mainly to preserve whitespace in `w:t` elements.

If for example you have the following WordML code:

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Test  </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>test</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Word will ignore the space in the first `w:t` and write **Testtest**, unless the preserve space attribute is present.

Best remove and add it using XSLT:

```
<xsl:attribute name="xml:space">preserve</xsl:attribute>
```